# XML in to a PHP does not display an array

Tags: php, xml, arr

I need to display an array PHP of data from file XML (https://pogoda.yandex.ru/static/cities.xml). I want in array all "id". Help me find the error. Thanks

```
<?php
 $data_file_city="https://pogoda.yandex.ru/static/cities.xml"; 
 $xml_city = simplexml_load_file($data_file_city); 

  foreach($xml_city->country as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value->city as $key1=>$value1) {
      $id = array("$value1[country]");
        echo $id;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `array("$value1[country]")`? What is this?

Comment: you are defining '$id' as an `array`, use `print_r($id)` to display the content, or remove the `array()` part from `$id=`

Comment: I need this array for use in JS loop. I get only the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `$value1` in your `foreach` is a SimpleXMLElement Object with attributes.

To get attributes of such object use [`attributes`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) function:

```
$ids = array();
$countries = array();
foreach($xml_city->country as $key=>$value){
    foreach ($value->city as $key1=>$value1) { 
        $attrs = $value1->attributes();

        // Use `strval` function to cast attribute value to `string` type

        // get `id` attribute 
        $id = strval($attrs['id']);

        // get `country` attribute
        $country = strval($attrs['country']);

        echo $id, '<br />', $country;

        // add to array
        $ids[] = $id;
        $countries[] = $country;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helps

Comment: One moment. I need these arrays for use in JS loop. And I need each value separately. How can I do this?

Comment: I don;t understand your question. You can't add item to array or what?

Comment: Syntax of adding to array is `$myArray[] = $id`. It is php basics. refer to manuals.

Comment: and how can I get the content between the tags (city name) in array (I'm not php developer)?

Comment: `strval($value1)`, next time you want to ask a question - make some effort, read a manual page.